# CSV generated by Java-Servlet: Encoding always "undefined"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, encoding

I am creating a CSV-File in my Java-Servlet.

I am setting everything to UTF-8:

```
response.setContentType("text/csv;charset=UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"shippingInfosForDHLImport.csv\"");
```

If I access my servlet in the browser and download the file, special cases are broken and if I open the file in sublime and type: "view.encoding()" to the console it shows me:

```
"u'Undefined'"
```

The servlet is running on google app engine and I am downloading the file to a Mac.

If I run the servlet locally. Everything works fine and the encoding in sublime is shown as UTF-8 (even if I remove the UTF-8 settings in my code).

How can I get the encoding for the file right, if the code is running on App engine? Is there another config param I can set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the Problem by writing my CSV content to the PrintWriter:

```
response.getWriter().write(result);
```

instead of to the OutputStream:

```
response.getOutputStream().write(result);
```